# Check nerd tree is open function

Tags: vimscript, functions, plugin-nerdtree

I'm trying to create a simple function in vim which lets me map `<leader>b`, `<leader>n`, and `<leader>0` to execute a function that checks if a nerd tree is open then cycle tabs and do `:NerdTreeFind` if not then only cycle tabs. but I couldn't seem to make it work and it returns `E121: Undefined variable: CR`

here is the script

```
function! CheckNerdTree(tab)
    if exists("g:NERDTree") && g:NERDTree.IsOpen()
        execute a:tab<CR>:NERDTreeFind<CR><C-w>l<CR>
    else
        execute a:tab<CR>
    endif
endfunction


noremap <leader>0 :call CheckNerdTree(":tablast")
noremap <leader>n :call CheckNerdTree(":tabnext")
noremap <leader>b :call CheckNerdTree(":tabprev")
```

I'm pretty new to vim scripting and haven't really 100% understand how it works, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Aside: you probably want `nnoremap` for normal mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execute command takes a string as an argument. Further, it is used to execute Ex commands. Finally, Ex-commands may be « executed » (in the programmatic sense, not the vimscript sense!) by simply calling them.

So we can simplify to

```
execute a:tab
NERDTreeFind
wincmd l
```

And

```
execute a:tab
```

---

Don’t forget the `<CR>`s at the end of the mapping

Comment: I recommend Steve Losh’s Learn Vimscript the Hard Way for beginners.

Comment: wow thankyou!, adding your solution and changing the noremaps into ```noremap <silent><leader>0 :call CheckNerdTree(":tablast")<cr>``` makes it perfect!

Comment: @millenito happy to help :)